# Formatting data for use with anosim() funciton

Tags: r, vegan

I have some data in the form:

```
 Year Altitude Habitat Guild     Count
 2008 1834     Primary Omnivore  6
 ...  ...      ...     ...       ...
```

Where

- Years = 2008, 2011, or 2014
- Habitat = Primary or Secondary
- Guild = Carnivore, Omnivore, Frugivore, Nectarivore or Insectivore
- Altitude and count are continuous

Thre are 695 samples

I would like to perform an ANOSIM test on the data however it is in a different format to any examples I have been able to find. To confirm I am using the right function here is what I am trying find out about the data:

Whether the composition of guilds differs significantly between habitats and if it changes over the years.
Additionally I would like to know if altitude is a confounding variable.

All my attempts thus so far have yielded nothing worth posting as a starting point.

Comment: Consider posting this on cross-validated community (stats.stackexchanges.com) as it is clearly more a methodological question than a programmation one.

Comment: Well the main question is how do I use the ANOMSIM function correctly with the data, I simply thought I would check that it was the correct function to use, but this area is hardly my forte so I cede that you are probably right

Comment: ANOSIm is possibly OK here, but the format is wrong - at least for most multivariate analysis tools in R. You want the data in wide format, where each Guild level is a column with the count values in the cells, one row per sample.